# "ERROR db._checkNotDeleted is not a function" when trying to update my database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make simple sign-in function for my web using firebase however I'm getting an error saying:
`ERROR db._checkNotDeleted is not a function`

my Firebase versions is 9 and React is running on 17.0.2.

This is my firebase config file snippet (Will hide configurations since its unnecessary):

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, collection, addDoc, getDocs, query, where} from "firebase/firestore";



const firebaseConfig = {
  */*/*/*/
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export const auth = getAuth(app);

  export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
    if(!userAuth) return;

    const docRef = doc(db, "users", `${userAuth.uid}`);
    
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (!docSnap.exists()) {
      const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
      const createdAt = new Date();
    
     
      try {
        await set(ref(db, 'users/' + `${userAuth.uid}`), {
          displayName: "TEST"
        })
        console.log("HERE");
       
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR", error.message);
      }
    }
    return docRef;
  }

  
  

  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
      signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      })
  }
 
  
  
  const db = getFirestore();
```

Here is my project: https://github.com/poolpy111/oto-clothing/tree/master/src

In debugger error line appears on line 43 which is where I use firebase's "ref" method.
What I'm supposed to do?

Comment: updated my post with project link. Thanks

Comment: Which database are you trying to use? You are creating document references (from Firestore) but using `set()` from Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: I have no clue what is realtime Database. I'm using "Firestore" database as it says in the console. In the latest Documentation snippet has "ref" in it, however it does not work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try refactoring the code as in my answer. You essentially used realtime database SDK's `set()` to add a Firestore document which definitely won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase has two databases namely [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database) and [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore). In the provided code you are creating a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) by using `doc()` but then using `set()` imported from Realtime Database SDK which is causing the error.

If you want to add data in Firestore then import `setDoc()` from Firestore and refactor the code as shown below:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, setDoc, collection, addDoc, getDocs, query, where} from "firebase/firestore";

export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
  if(!userAuth) return;

  const docRef = doc(db, "users", `${userAuth.uid}`);
    
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (!docSnap.exists()) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();  
     
    try {
      // use setDoc()
      await setDoc(docRef, {
        displayName: "TEST"
      })
      console.log("HERE");   
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERROR", error.message);
    }
  }
  return docRef;
}
```

Follow [Firestore's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for more information.